# Uninitialized string offset: 1

Tags: php

I am confused with this warning ..
I 've tried but still so ..
how true ?

```
public static function RF_GetSize($url) {
    $x = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1), CASE_LOWER);
    return (strcasecmp($x[0], 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') != 0) ? $x['content-length'][1] : $x['content-length'];
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: thanks if you can help , in this line ..

return (strcasecmp($x[0], 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') != 0) ? $x['content-length'][1] : $x['content-length'];

Comment: I got the message as PHP Notice : Uninitialized string offset : 1 in /home/mayalove/public_html/ex.php on line 28

Comment: What is `$x['content-length']`?  It is either an empty string or string with 1 character.

Comment: No friends , maybe even all goes well ,, it 's just very annoying error message ..
is there maybe another way to hide the message above ..

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php, 'content-length' is not an array, so you can't do

```
$x['content-length'][1]
```

because $x['content-length'] is (most likely) a numeric string. What are you trying to do with that piece of code?

Reading more regarding get_headers(), it seems that it *will* spit out an array for each header element if there were redirections done. In any case, that part of your code is still unclear to me.